# MVC - Can a "SelectList" return the selected object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

Got a List of objects, likaso (pseudo code):

```
class PersonViewModel{name, age, etc}
class MyObjectViewModel
{
    //actually comes from WebService, but that doesnt matter here
    List<PersonViewModel> AllPeople= {person1,person2, etc}
    PersonViewModel SelectedPerson;
}
```

So i want to allow user to select a person from a drop down:

```
@model MyModels.MyObjectViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(MyObjectViewModel=> MyObjectViewModel.SelectedPerson , new SelectList(Model.AllPeople))
```

The view and dropdowns are correctly populated.

When I clicks submit the Controller always gets myObjectViewModel.SelectedPerson == Null.
Why isnt it returning anything? How can I return the selected object?

Comment: Is there a difference in type between the value of your select list and your selected person member var?

Comment: No i corrected the example (after checking in code), its all view models:
here the class actual code: 
' [Display(Name = "Titular")] public EntidadeViewModel Titular { get; set; } public List<EntidadeViewModel> Titulares { get; set; }'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.DropDownListFor` can not create `PersonViewModel` as selected person. Although it can return an `Id` of selected person and you will have to get all othr fields from your service/session/database and etc. Assuming that `PersonViewModel` has an `Id` and `Name` properties this is what you should do:

```
class MyObjectViewModel
{
    //actually comes from WebService, but that doesnt matter here
    List<PersonViewModel> AllPeople= {person1,person2, etc}
    int SelectedPersonId;
}

@model MyModels.MyObjectViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.SelectedPersonId, 
      Model.AllPeople.Select(p=>new SelectListItem{Value = p.Id, Text=p.Name}))
```

In the action that you are posting to you will get MyObjectViewModel.SelectedPersonId filled with the id of selected person. Than you will be able to use it in order to get your `PersonViewModel`

Comment: Correct, it only uses simple classes. Just found more simple to do this:
`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPersonId, new SelectList(Model.AllPeople, "Id", "Name"))` it becomes more understandable.